# BOM Explosion with Blanks

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple BOM table that contains a parent and a child column.
Every row contains values. There are no blanks.
To bring that table into a BI-Tool I need to add blank values for the parents, like here shown:
[image]

As you can see, if an EntityKay has no parent key, then there should be a blank value.
How would you do that?

Example:

Current State:

```
Child   Parent
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   3
9   3
```

Needed Result:

```
Child   Parent
1   
2   
3   
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   3
9   3
```

Comment: The *blank value* is typically called a `NULL`.  Could you show (in text form not as an image) your data and the *expected result*?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! I added the current state as well as the expected result.

Comment: I don't get it at all.  Where do children 7, 8, and 9 come from?

Comment: They are just related to Parent  = 3 as a "sub category". Like 4, 5 and 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query provides the *missing keys*, i.e. the *parents*, that are *no childs* are selected with the parent `null`

```
select distinct Parent Child, null Parent from bom
where Parent not in (select Child from bom)
order by 1;


     CHILD PARENT
---------- ------
         1       
         2       
         3
```

You must add those records (with an `INSERT`) to your table and probably `update` additionaly the description.

```
insert into bom (Child, Parent)
select distinct Parent Child, null Parent from bom
where Parent not in (select Child from bom)
```

Result

```
select * from bom;

     CHILD     PARENT
---------- ----------
         4          1
         5          1
         6          2
         7          3
         8          3
         9          3
         2           
         3           
         1
```

To get the extended data *without modifying* the table use an `UNION ALL` of the ofiginal table with the query providing the missing part.

You may add also the *names* for the new rows using the `DECODE` as show below in the example

```
select   
   Child,  Parent, name 
from BOM union all
select distinct 
  Parent Child, null Parent, 
  decode(Parent,1,'North America',2,'Europa',3,'Asia')
from bom
where Parent not in (select Child from bom)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use UPDATE since I just have ready-only rights. I just want to extract data from an existing table.

Comment: Added the solution without an `UPDATE` @joshua